# Peripendicular distance from a line segment

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a line given by $Ax + By + C= 0$, and a point $x0,y0$. From that point $x0,y0$ in the direction of the line up to distance $d$, I want to find the perpendicular distance of the points from this line segment.

In the figure, below I wish to calculate this only for $x1,y1$ and $x4,y4$. The points $x2,y2$ and $x3,y3$ should be excluded as they lie above the red line depicted.
Please check figure below:[image]

Comment: I just can't understand this question, and the diagram helps nothing: what does "finding points that are less than distance" mean at all? You don't seem to be asking how to calculate the distance from $\;(x,y)\;$ to that line, but then what are you asking? And what is $\;d_2\;$ in the diagram, and how does it get defined?

Comment: @Timbuc yes, what are saying makes more sense. I tend to do that.

Comment: Sorry I am not much good at mathematics notations, can you please the point that is unclear.

Comment: Explaining more it is easy to calculate perpendicular of a point from a line. But how do to so in case of a line segment.

Comment: So essentially  I wish to exclude the two points above slightly rotated horizontal line.

Comment: Do you actually want to have a line given by $Ax+By+C=0$ and a point $x,y$ _on that line?_ If so, it would make things much clearer if you wrote it that way. Also, it's a bit confusing to use the same variables $x,y$ to denote general points on the line (or in the plane) and also to denote a particular fixed point. It would be clearer if your special point were named something else, perhaps $(x_0,y_0)$. Note that when you use a list of coordinates such as this to name a point, it's conventional to enclose the list in parentheses.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks! Point taken. Please the question now.

Comment: If your problem statement is correct, then the constraint $Ax_0+By_0+C=0$ must hold.

Comment: The problem statement is incomplete as nothing tells you the orientation of the line.

Comment: The red line is perpendicular to $Ax+By+C=0$. Sorry, for mentioning before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translate all points so that $(x_0,y_0)$ becomes $(0,0)$.

The unit vector $(a,b):=(A,B)/\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ is perpendicular to the black line, so that a vector $(x,y)$ decomposes as $d_\perp=(a,b)\cdot(x,y)$ and $d_\parallel=(b,-a)\cdot(x,y)$.

The answer is given by $|d_\perp|$ if $0\le d_\parallel\le d$.

Comment: I think these formulas are equivalent (in the end) to what I wrote up, but in a much neater and more concise notation.

Comment: One doubt: if "(black) line" means the black line in the OP's diagram, I think OP wanted $|d_\perp|$ if $0\le d_\parallel\le d$. (The "$0 \le$" part isn't completely clear, but now that you point it out I suppose it may be part of OP's desired outcome.)

Comment: Yep, I fixed the typo, thanks.  As the problem statement is a little ambiguous, I mixed algebraic and absolute distances. Of course, our formulas are the same, but normalization helps. One can also say "WLOG (by a change of coordinates), the line is $x=0$ and the point $(0,0)$" :-)

Comment: Normalization indeed helps! (That's why I gave this answer its first upvote; it's a significant improvement.) Aside from the obvious benefits, your normalization constant eliminates that annoying $\varepsilon$ that I had to spend so many words explaining.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Can you please clarify the following :How to 
Translate all points and I am not familiar with using dot product to calculate distances. If possible can you elucidate more on the above. Sry, I am not from a mathematical background.

Comment: Subtract $x_0$ and $y_0$ from all coordinates. Products are $ax+by$ and $bx-ay$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for the reply! What about the equation of the line perpendicular to black line(.i.e., red line). Shouldn't that change as well in the new coordinate system?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Two questions: 1. When transforming the coordinate system,does the rotation of axis also affect the  coordinates in the new system 2. What I am confused over the following : given the equation $Ax+By+C=0$ in the normal coordinate system, how can I calculate the perpendicular vector in the new coordinate system. Requesting to be excused for the problem I give you.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: my solution completely lavishes you from caring about the change of coordinates. Anyway, to answer you, the black line is $d_\perp=0$ and the red one $d_\parallel=d$, and $(x,y)$ becomes $(d_\perp,d_\parallel)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for explantation! Following what you said I tried to code it, but it gave incorrect results in terms simulations. Please check is there is something wrong in my methodology: Given $Ax+By+C=0$ I get the perpendicular unit vector as $B/\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ , $-A/\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$. For each point, that I have to check. Given it's coordinates are $x_1,y_1$(not transformed.) I simply compute $d_\perp$  and $d_\parallel$ using dot product.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I doubt lies not using $x_0,y_0$ anywhere. Should I subtract $x_1,y_1$ by $x_0,y_0$ before taking the dot product?

Comment: indeed, from all points.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for the reply! By all the points you mean $x_1,y_1;x_2,y_2;x_3,y_3;x_4,y_4$ in the figure drawn in the question. Can you please explain why the perpendicular unit vector remains same in both the coordinate systems and shouldn't be transformed. Sorry, again if the question is naive, I have forgetten almost everything about geometry.

Comment: @YvesDaoust the formula seems print opposite signs for $d_\parallel$ for $x_1,y_1$ and $x_4,y_4$ in the above figure. Can you please check again? Should take the absolute of $d_\parallel$?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: no, you are confusing $\perp$ and $\parallel$.

Answer (score 2):

The distance $d(P,D)$ of your $P$ with coordinates $(x_P,y_P)$ to the line $D \equiv Ax+By+X=0$ is given by the formula $$d(P,D) = \frac{\vert Ax_P + By_P+C \vert}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$

Comment: I mentioned this in my first comment: I doubt highly this is what the OP meant to ask. OTOH, I've no idea what he actually meant to ask...

Comment: The line $Ax+By+C=0$ is constrained upto a distance d from point x,y in it's direction. Thus, in addition to the above it should exclude points which lie beyond d as well.

Comment: Does this make sense?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you precise the way the line is constrainted? What are the circles in your drawing?

Comment: Circles are simply points.

Comment: Line constrained- In the direction of the line from point x,y up to distance d. So say I am standing on x,y. Now I look in direction of the line and walk a distance d from x,y.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Please the question edit now with the new figure. Hope it makes it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

As best I can understand the question, what you really want to do is
related to this figure:

[image: coordinate system]

Here we see your point $(x_0, y_0)$, the line $L$ given by $Ax+By+C=0$,
and the $x$- and $y$-coordinate axes with respect to which
those $x$ and $y$ coordinates are defined.
(I am assuming you meant for the line $L$
to pass through the point $(x_0, y_0)$.)

The figure also shows a line $M$ through $(x_0, y_0)$
perpendicular to the line $L$.
Together, these two lines define a transformed coordinate system
that is translated and rotated with respect to the $x,y$ coordinate system.
An arbitrary point $(x,y)$ somewhere in the plane, as shown in the figure,
has coordinates $(x',y')$ in the transformed system, where
$x'$ is measured parallel to $L$ and $y'$ is measured perpendicular to $L$.

Your red line appears near the upper right corner of the figure,
perpendicular to the line $L$.
The distance from the line $M$ to the red line is $d$.
The equation of the red line
(in the transformed coordinate system) would be $x' = d.$

It is my understanding that for such an arbitrary point $(x,y)$,
with transformed coordinates $(x',y')$,
you want to know first of all whether $x' \leq d$.
If $x' \leq d$, you then want to know the value of $|y'|$,
which is the perpendicular distance from $(x,y)$ to the line $L$
given by $Ax+By+C=0$.
If $x' > d$, then $x'$ is on the "wrong" side of the red line
and you are not interested in its distance from the line $L$.

The transformed coordinates are found by the equations

$$x' = \frac{\varepsilon (B(x - x_0) - A(y - y_0))}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}}$$
$$y' = \frac{\varepsilon (A(x - x_0) + B(y - y_0))}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}}$$

where $\varepsilon$ is a constant and $\varepsilon=1$ or $\varepsilon=-1$
depending on which of those two values produces the desired sign of $x'$.
For a point at coordinates $(x,y)$, compute $x'$ according to the
equation above; then, if $x'\leq d$, compute $|y'|$.

The reason for $\varepsilon$ is so that the red line will be in the
desired direction from $(x_0,y_0)$: one value of $\varepsilon$ will
cause the line $x'=d$ to be to the right of $(x_0,y_0)$
and the other value of $\varepsilon$ will cause the line to be to the left.
Which value of $\varepsilon$ puts the line on which side depends on the
signs of $A$ and $B$.
You can figure out which value of $\varepsilon$ to use by trial and error:
set a value of $\varepsilon$,
choose a point $(x,y)$ that is obviously on the "wrong" side of the
red line, and compute that point's $x'$ coordinate.
If $x' > d$, you have set $\varepsilon$ to the correct value;
otherwise you should reverse the sign of $\varepsilon$.

Note that because taking the absolute value cancels the sign of $y'$,
and because we assumed that $Ax_0 + By_0 + C = 0,$
the formula for $|y'|$ using the equation above is equal to the
usual formula for finding the distance of a point from a line
given by $Ax + By + C = 0$,
$$|y'| = \frac{|Ax + By + C|}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}}.$$

Comment: You explained the question way better than me! I still confused over e

Comment: You can wait a while longer to see if any other helpful answers are posted, but don't forget to accept the answer you like best at the end. (It doesn't have to be mine!) Otherwise your question will be hang out in the archives "forever" in the "unanswered" state, as if it's still waiting for a satisfactory resolution.

Comment: @DavidK: Is the drawing done in tikz (or pgfplots)?

Comment: @user170039 I drew the figure in OpenOffice Draw.